# Column names converted to lowercase in Postgres: How to deal with this issue mid-project

Tags: node.js, postgresql, api, express

I'm building an ExpressJS API with Postgres as my Database.

For my `users` table I have **four** columns: `(id, firstName, lastName, password)`

While testing the API, I found that console-logging `console.log(user.firstName)` or `console.log(user.lastName)` prints undefined... but logging `console.log(user.id)` or `console.log(user.password)` returns that id or password. Later on I discovered that this is because I didn't use double quotes `" "` while naming the columns in my database migration and hence Postgres converted the uppercase letter in `firstName` and `lastName` to lowercase.

My question is, what should I do now?

One solution would be to **create a new migration** to alter the column names using double quotes.

Another solution would be to **change every occurrence** of (`firstName` to `firstname`) and (`lastName` to `lastname`)

Which of these would be considered the better solution? (Also open for any other suggestions)

Comment: Change `firstName` to `firstname`, keeping track of mixed case is not worth the effort.

Comment: Postgres lower cases all identifiers that are not doubled quoted; therefore, `T1.firstName` and `t1.firstname` reference the same column of the same table. So you can use mixed case names as long as you **do not double quote** them. I noticed you declared you had a table `users` then indicated a error that `user.firstname` does not exist. Perhaps that is due to incorrect table name?

Comment: Yes, it is best to stick with standard conforming identifiers and avoid double quotes.